# error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _fltused in wdk

Tags: wdk

I am trying to define a double data type variable in a C code which is going to be used in the Windows kernel. The code compiles but gives error while linking. I tried using libcntpr.lib in the source file and also defining __fltused variable in the code but to no avail. I'll really appreciate if someone can help me on how to use this.

Answer (score 8):

Don't know if still applicable to current WDK but Walter Oney demotivates the use of floating point stuff in drivers [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!msg/comp.os.ms-windows.programmer.drivers/qeEAshA7cRc/wRk1WZndqAcJ).

> The problem is worse than just finding the right library,
>   unfortunately. The C compiler's floating point support assumes that it
>   will be operating in a an application environment where you can
>   initialize the coprocessor, install some exception handlers, and then
>   blast away. It also assumes that the operating system will take care
>   of saving and restoring each thread's coprocessor context as required
>   by all the thread context switches that occur from then on.
>
> These assumptions aren't usually true in a driver. Furthermore, the
>   runtime library support for coprocessor exceptions can't work because
>   there's a whole bunch of missing infrastructure.
>
> What you basically need to do is write your code in such a way that
>   you initialize the coprocessor each time you want to use it (don't
>   forget KeSaveFloatingPointState and KeRestoreFloatingPointState). Set
>   things up so that the coprocessor will never generate an exception,
>   too. Then you can simply define the symbol __fltused somewhere to
>   satisfy the linker. (All that symbol usually does is drag in the
>   runtime support. You don't want that support becuase, as I said, it
>   won't work in kernel mode.) You'll undoubtedly need some assembly
>   language code for the initialization steps.
>
> If you have a system thread that will be doing all your floating point
>   math, you can initialize the coprocesor once at the start of the
>   thread. The system will save and restore your state as necessary from
>   then on.
>
> Don't forget that you can only do floating point at IRQL <
>   DISPATCH_LEVEL.
>
> There's FINIT, among other things. If you're rusty on coprocessor
>   programming, my advice would be to tell your management that this is a
>   specialized problem that will require a good deal of study to solve.
>   Then fly off to Martinique for a week or so (after hurricane season,
>   that is) to perform the study in an appropriate environment.
>
> Seriously, if you're unfamiliar with FINIT and other math coprocessor
>   instructions, this is probably not something you should be
>   incorporating into your driver.

There is also an interesting read from Microsoft: [C++ for Kernel Mode Drivers: Pros and Cons](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/gg487420.aspx)

> On x86 systems, the floating point and multimedia units are not
>   available in kernel mode unless specifically requested. Trying to use
>   them improperly may or may not cause a floating-point fault at raised
>   IRQL (which will crash the system), but it could cause silent data
>   corruption in random processes. Improper use can also cause data
>   corruption in other processes; such problems are often difficult to
>   debug.